# jQuery addClass

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery

I am a self confessed jQuery novice but I am conscious of learning the correct techniques. When I can see repetition like this I just know that there must be a better way.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o44yy3mg/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var project1 = $('section').eq(0).offset();
    var project2 = $('section').eq(1).offset();
    var project3 = $('section').eq(2).offset();
    var project4 = $('section').eq(3).offset();
    var project5 = $('section').eq(4).offset();
    var project6 = $('section').eq(5).offset();
    var $window = $(window);

    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ( $window.scrollTop() >= project1.top) {
            $("header").removeClass().addClass("project1");
        }
        if ( $window.scrollTop() >= project2.top ) {
            $("header").removeClass().addClass("project2");
        }
        if ( $window.scrollTop() >= project3.top ) {
            $("header").removeClass().addClass("project3");
        }
        if ( $window.scrollTop() >= project4.top ) {
            $("header").removeClass().addClass("project4");
        }
        if ( $window.scrollTop() >= project5.top ) {
            $("header").removeClass().addClass("project5");
        }
        if ( $window.scrollTop() >= project6.top ) {
            $("header").removeClass().addClass("project6");
        }
    });         
});
```

Comment: Review the code/run the tests at http://jsperf.com/caching-jquery-selectors/6 for some refactoring ideas.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- Since section elements are being retrieved in a sequence, a `for` loop can be used.
- Since the scroll event can happen frequently, store the header selection in a variable outside of the event.
- `$window.scrollTop()` is called multiple times, making it a good candidate to be stored in a variable.

Condensed version of the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $header = $("header");
    var numberOfSections = 6;   
    var sectionOffsets = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < numberOfSections + 1; i++) {
        sectionOffsets.push($('section').eq(i).offset());            
    }            

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();            

        for(var i = 0; i < numberOfSections + 1; i++) {
             if(scrollTop > sectionOffsets[i].top) {
                $header.removeClass().addClass("project" + (i + 1));                         
             }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is it necessary to name the number of sections? Could that be removed so that it could be any number?

Comment: I did it by using section.length http://jsfiddle.net/o44yy3mg/3/

Comment: I am still gettin an error that says that it cannot read top of undefined

Comment: Hello, I edited the code so that the undefined error would no longer occur in the fiddle provided.  See the updated version at http://jsfiddle.net/o44yy3mg/3/.  To summarize, you don't have to add 1 to the number of iterations the loop will run when selecting by the tag 'section'.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $window = $(window), 
        $sections = $('section'), 
        $header = $('header');

    var elementMatchesViewport = function(data, index, element) {        
        return (data.scrollTop >= $(element).offset().top) ? true : false;
    };

    var setHeaderClassFromElementIndex = function(data, index, element) {
        var classString = 'project' + parseInt($(element).index() + 1, 10);
        data.$header
            .removeClass()
            .addClass(classString);
    };

    var handleScroll = function(data, event) {
        var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
        data.$sections
            .filter($.proxy(elementMatchesViewport, this, {scrollTop: scrollTop}))
            .each($.proxy(setHeaderClassFromElementIndex, this, {$header: $header}));
    };

    $window.on('scroll', $.proxy(handleScroll, this, {$sections: $sections}));

});
```

Possible further enhancements:

- Use a zero-based index for your header classes.
- Debounce the scroll event / use request animation frame, as it's performance intensive.
- Refactor the condition of elementMatchesViewport() as it matches too many elements.

[jsFillde](http://jsfiddle.net/mlnmln/ghcshx6e/)